# HP ALM - how to calculate the time between a defect was reported and it was fixed?

Tags: hp-alm

I am looking for finding the time between a defect was fixed minus it was reported. The data I am trying to collect is how fast the developer could fix a defect.

'The actual fix time' field essentially considers date closed minus creation date so it really cannot help with that I am trying to achieve.

is there a query that I can use to get this data?

ALM version I have is 12.53